# Is "the empty" intersects with all sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We know "the empty set" is the subset of every set and there is only one empty set(from Axiom of extensionality), then it must be in intersection with (kind of intersection point) all sets, otherwise all sets could not contain the same thing as a subset because there are disjoint sets etc.

- Thus, all sets intersect through empty set, so all sets intersects with each other through empty set. (Thus, empty set is a kind of big bang point of nothing where all universe is created. >:)

So, are these inferences true?

Comment: Not clear what "intersection point" means... But Yes: $A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$ for every set $A$.

Comment: In a sense, in [Axiomatic Set Theory : Von Neumann universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe) all universe is created from the empty set. Thus, in an imaginative way, it is created *ex nihilo*.

Comment: *Thus, empty set is a kind of big bang point of nothing where all universe is created.* --- See the [Von Neumann hierarchy for set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe). *(seconds later)* It appears @Mauro ALLEGRANZA  had the same thought that I did, about half a minute earlier.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I edited "intersection point", just thinking visually, you are right its out concept.

Comment: But to say that "all sets intersects with each other through empty set" can be misleading: $A \cap A= A$ also when $A$ is not empty. And e.g. $\mathbb N \cap \mathbb Q= \mathbb N$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But its about all sets and "the single empty set", not a single set being subset of itself.

Comment: But again, if you imagine to intersect in a single shot **all** sets, for sure the result will be the empty set, because in the "collection" of all sets also the emptyset is included.

Comment: So, that's why i actually wonder, if we have one and only one empty set, then it is a kind of intersection with every set  so it could be in intersection or subset of all sets. So, instead of thinking it in every set, thinking it at intersecting with every set would be clear i think.

Comment: No, it's not "a big bang point of nothing where all universe is created", rather "a big bang point of nothing where all OUR CONCEPTS of a universe are created". Don't mix theory and reality.

Comment: @its_me Yep I am just gagging. But I think your point is good, it's the point where all our concepts are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some brief comment :

1. The set of all sets is really not a set (in usual context).
2. You may check Von Neumann Universe (V), Constructible Universe (L) and V=L in order to back up/challenge your "big bang" analogy.

Comment: So you mean by set of all sets the universal set which is not allowed in ZFC.

Comment: Yeah, 1. was written before you edited the question. I just meant that if you take an intersection over the collection of all sets, you're not taking an intersection over a collection which is a set (at least in ZFC). You can still make sense of it if you introduce classes (or if you work in a system which "allows" them). But I guess that now, only 2. remains (hopefully) meaningful/useful for your question!

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

Yes, empty set is a subset of all sets.

However, no, it is not an intersection, because it would require defining things differently. We would have to say not "this equation does not have a solution", but rather "this equation has a solution which happens to belong to an empty set".

This means that we would say that $x^2+1=0$ and $x^4+1=0$ have a common solution among real numbers, even though these solutions belong to an empty set. But they do not have a common solution.

So the empty set, although unique, is not unique regarding its genesis. If you say that all triangles with 4 sides and all prime numbers divisible by 8 intersect and that intersection is an empty set, you will not be able to use regular set operations, unless you define a set of all triangles with 4 sides *and* all prime numbers divisible by 8.

I am saying that in order to say that an empty set is an intersection of the two above, first you have to define a sufficiently general set of things.

So, in order to say an empty set is an intersection of all sets, first you have to combine all these sets and create a set that contains whatever element you want. Then each particular set can, but does not, contain every element type.

So you would need, in our example, to say, there is a set of of all triangles with 4 sides and all prime numbers divisible by 8, and then you give two examples, one set that contains *only* triangles, and one set that contains all prime numbers. While these two sets contain a specific type, both are able to contain the other type as well.

Only then you can talk about the intersection of both being an empty set.

This would bring you to defining first a set that can contain *any* element. Then each set of a specific type (like prime numbers) would be a subset of this set.

There is a big trouble when we say "a set that can contain anything". There are many paradoxes that lead to nowhere and set theory has restricted the definitions in order to tailor and avoid these.

Even though a set looks like a generic object, it really is not. It is defined by the type of the object it contains. There is always some set of operations and relations among the elements. These definitions do not vanish when we talk about the empty set.

Look at the empty set of all odd numbers and empty set of all even numbers. The empty set  is one and the same. Sure. But try to add an element to that unique empty set. You can add an element to an empty set, right? But, which element to add? Odd or even? You cannot, right?

That is the problem. Empty set is frozen-ly unique, because it has no property on its own. Yet as soon as you try to do something with it, it requires attaching it to something first and then do the required operation.

Comment: I think about frozenly uniqueness too but when we use it as subset of some set then could we think it as subset of another too?

Comment: @lockedscope No, unless you extend and create a set that can contain both type of elements first, elements from one and from the other set. But then, in order to talk about empty set being intersection of every set, you have to define a set that can contain anything, and there comes the problem. You cannot do that.

Comment: Sorry, i accept JPA's answer as answered first and leads to same conclusions but your answer is very comprehensive, if possible i'd like accept both. By the way i am sold with your answer that there is a set of all sets so i am not sure whether if i must select your answer, i am caught in the middle. There might be some multiple answer choice, comprehensive answer, winner answer etc.

Comment: @lockedscope As you can see I am a temp user, not with a completed sign up, then you can imagine how much I care about any voting machine ;) It is important that I am understood and that it helps.
The question you ask cuts really deep into category theory. There is no empty set as such to be used without some property attached to it. One general property that might help is to attach the number of elements, 0 in case of the empty set. Then you can say that all other sets with some number of elements 0 or not, have an intersection in the empty set (regarding the number of elements: implied).

Comment: Thank you Aleksandar Perisic. So, could we say that we should not compare empty sets of different contexts? Also, what could we do with the fact that there is only one empty set? Can you given an example for its usage?

Comment: On the other hand, we know all empty sets are same but we can't do anything with this information, can we?

Comment: @lockedscope Its complement is useful. It is exactly the set we were talking about here. The universal set. However, notice the this "universality" is always within some theory. So you could say, there is the unique empty set up to some theory. If you want to talk about an empty set from two theories, then you need to unify these theories first. Within one theory you do have your intersection. A universal empty set outside any theory or encompassing all theories might still exist but it is not the empty set that is defined through the axiom of Extensions, for example.

Comment: I think empty sets are equal (when they are unfreezed) for some sets by the axiom of extensionality, just with their number of elements, 0.

Comment: @lockedscope By that, using number of elements, we are talking about the empty set within the theory of Measure.

Comment: Oops it's a bit misleading, I mean if and only if they have same elements(by extensionality) so empty sets do not have any elements so they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** they are subsets
but *not intersections* of all sets because of venn diagram of such set doesn't exist
Moreover comparing it with big bang we infer that nothing is member of everything **i.e. null set is member of **universal set** which is practically not possible.**